# How to upscale an entire webpage to look the same in a 4K monitor as in an HD one?

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive, scaling

Is it possible to use HTML meta tags or CSS to scale an entire webpage to adhere properly to different screen sizes, and if yes, then how? I tried `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`.

This is what I'm working on: https://osamabodiaf.com/ (The scaling issues are very noticeable at 4K)

PS: This is not to be confused with responsive design that deals with different kinds of devices, this is meant to deal with same-kind devices that have similar screen ratios and only differ in resolution. In other words, I would like to avoid using @media queries and define new styles for each element. I appreciate your time.

Comment: This has very much to do with responsive design. In fact, responsive design means designing for different screen sizes, not different devices. If you want to preserve the "true" size you have to work with relative units, such as vw (viewport-width).

Comment: I understand I can do it that way, but... there is no better way?